# refactor codes using visitor pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, refactoring

I am having problem when trying to refactor my codes. It is in a compiler like structure.
The code structure is as follow.
I have several target platform to generate my code like x86.

```
class Op
{
public:
  virtual doA(vector<int>& vec) = 0;
  virtual doB(unordered_map<int>& map) = 0;
};

---Directory x86----
class X86_Op_A: public Op 
{
public:
  virtual doA(vector<int>& vec){
      // genereate A type operator that do something under x86
  }
  virtual doB(unordered_map<int>& map){
     // genereate A type operator that do something under x86
  }
};

class X86_Op_B: public Op
public:
  virtual doA(vector<int>& vec){
      // genereate B type operator that do something under x86
  }
  virtual doB(unordered_map<int>& map){
     // genereate B type operator that do something under x86
  }
}; 

---Director arm---
class Arm_Op_A: public Op 
class Arm_Op_B: public Op
like the same code described above.
```

How can I refactor the code so that they look like visitor pattern and I can just give it my target platform and the operation I want to do.

I have tried thinking about writing an abstract platform interface and implemented with different target planform. However, I still find it hard to write the code correctly. If I cannot use visitor pattern in this case, is there any way to refactor the code ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm a bit confused with your question. The visitor pattern lets you define an operation without changing the class of the object on which it operates. All you need is a new class with a member function that takes an ``Op *`` as a parameter. Is this what you are after?

Comment: My main point is to refactor the total cpp files I have. Currently, under different target platform, I have to write some duplicate codes. And after I read design pattern, I think maybe I can use visitor to help reduce the duplicate codes. But when I am trying to apply this to my code, I found ti hard to reach my target. So, I post my question here and hope to find a solution. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I can't see any code duplication in your question. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the duplicated code?

Comment: Sorry for not describing the problem more concretely. Since the original code is too complex and I haven't found a better way to post it online. And now, I have figure out some way to refactor my code using builder design pattern and some other trick including store some predefined function in my class. Anyway, thank you for your helping!  And I have a great experience when my first time using SO.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

The visitor pattern will be better if:
1 - For some reason you want to separate the doA and doB operations in different classes;
2 - Your classes X86_Op_A, X86_Op_B, Arm_Op_A, Arm_Op_B have other methods and you do not want the doA and doB operations to be together with these methods;

```
class X86_Op_A;
class X86_Op_B;
class Arm_Op_A;
class Arm_Op_B;

class OpVisitor
{
public:
    OpVisitor();
    virtual ~OpVisitor();
public:
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_A*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_B*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_A*) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_B*) = 0;
};
```

```
#include "OpVisitor.h"
#include "vector"
#include "iostream"

class DoAVisitor :
    public OpVisitor
{
public:
    DoAVisitor(std::vector<int>& vec): m_vec(vec)
    {
    }
    virtual ~DoAVisitor();
public:
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_A*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate A type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_B*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate B type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_A*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate A type operator that do something under Arm" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_B*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate B type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
protected:
    std::vector<int>& m_vec;
};
```

```
#include "OpVisitor.h"
#include "iostream"
#include "unordered_map"

class DoBVisitor :
    public OpVisitor
{
public:
    DoBVisitor(std::unordered_map<int, int>& map): m_map(map)
    {
    }
    virtual ~DoBVisitor();
public:
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_A*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate A type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(X86_Op_B*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate B type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_A*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate A type operator that do something under Arm" << "\n";
    }
    virtual void visit(Arm_Op_B*)
    {
        std::cout << "genereate B type operator that do something under x86" << "\n";
    }
protected:
    std::unordered_map<int, int>& m_map;
};
```

```
#include "Op.h"
#include "OpVisitor.h"

class X86_Op_A :
    public Op
{
public:
    X86_Op_A();
    virtual ~X86_Op_A();
public:
    virtual void Accept(OpVisitor& v)
    {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
```

```
#include "Op.h"
#include "OpVisitor.h"

class X86_Op_B :
    public Op
{
public:
    X86_Op_B();
    virtual ~X86_Op_B();
public:
    virtual void Accept(OpVisitor& v)
    {
        v.visit(this);
    }
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "X86_Op_A.h"
#include "DoAVisitor.h"
#include "vector"

int main()
{
    X86_Op_A var;

    std::vector<int> vec;

    DoAVisitor visitor(vec);

    var.Accept(visitor);

    std::cout << "Hello World!\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your concrete codes! Your code give me a lot of intuition to tackle the problem and help me understand when to use the visitor design pattern more! Really thanks for your helping. Although after I carefully check all the code I have, I think I should use other ways to refactor my code better.